# How can get a complete picture about streams in Java?

Tags: java, stream

Whenever I have to work with topics like file-handling or socket-programming, I have to look for sample code on the internet to see how the xxStreamxx,xxReader,xxWriter classes are used.
I want to be able to use them on my own and know how they work.

How do I go about learning that?

Comment: For future reference, the absolutely best place to start investigating some topic in Java is to check the tutorials on Sun/Oracle homepage (like advised below). I believe it's called "the trails". Here's a link; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ (makes a great bookmark, FYI :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to learn and understand what streams are. If you don't understand the concepts behind them, you will be always copying code. So read the "Basic I/O lesson of the java tutorial": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html. A comprehensive presentation about this topic is this one from javapassion.com: http://www.javapassion.com/javase/javaiostream.pdf.

While reading, as I usually told my students: "write code and make mistakes" :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is simple.

Streams are for binary read/write. Readers/Writers are for character read/write (in Java byte is not a char, since char is unicode). If it is possible to convert binary stream into character sequence, there is an appropriate reader for a stream.

For example, `FileInputStream extends InputStream` is ty read file binary. If this is textual file to read, you wrap this object into `InputStreamReader extends Reader` providing character set. Now you are able to read characters.

If you want to do `readLine()` you need to wrap this reader into `BufferedReader`.

Similarly with writers.

So, the idea is wrapping to get new abilities.

Answer (score 1):

In this website you could find a variety of examples on how to write your own streams in Java: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/WritingIOSC/

Just looking at the examples sometimes helps you much more than the explanations...

Please scroll to the middle and bottom of the page.